# Warning: max() [function.max]: Array must contain at least one element - whats is this?

Tags: php, mysql

So, im trying to do a poll, when i run mysql gives me this error, and i dont know what it means.

**Warning: max() [function.max]: Array must contain at least one element in .... in line 18.**

Could anyone please guide me of whats that?

This is my code:

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `poll` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($rows > 0){
    $poll = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $title = $poll['name'];
} else {
    $title = 'No Poll Yet';
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) as hits FROM `responses` GROUP BY `qid`");
$me = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $me[] = $row['hits'];
}
$max = max($me);    ////// THIS IS LINE 18

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `questions`.`pid` FROM  `responses`, `questions` WHERE     `responses`.`qid`=`questions`.`id` AND `responses`.`ip`='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' AND pid='".$poll['id']."'");
```

line 18 is noted after "//////"

Any help ? :s

Comment: That means the array `$me` is empty, which is probably because the query returned nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply what the error-message says: `$me` is an empty array (caused by your sql-query returning nothing - why this happens is hard to say without seeing your tablestructure and contents of the table)

Comment: Thank youu. Yess, what happens is that it will be looking for values on a table atribute, and it was empty, so i got that !.   as soon as i submited an entry error stoppp.   Thankkkssss.

Answer (score 2):

Just change in line number 18

```
if(!empty($me)) $max = max($me);
```

Full Code After Changes:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `poll` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($rows > 0){
    $poll = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $title = $poll['name'];
} else {
    $title = 'No Poll Yet';
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) as hits FROM `responses` GROUP BY `qid`");
$me = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $me[] = $row['hits'];
}
if(!empty($me)) $max = max($me);    ////// THIS IS LINE 18

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `questions`.`pid` FROM  `responses`, `questions` WHERE     `responses`.`qid`=`questions`.`id` AND `responses`.`ip`='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' AND pid='".$poll['id']."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be passing an empty array to the `max()` function. Just check the array is not empty before calling the `max()` or `min()` function. You can check by `count($arr) > 0`, Here are a few key points from the documentation.

`max()` in php, returns the parameter value considered "highest" according to standard comparisons. If multiple values of different types evaluate as equal (e.g. 0 and 'abc') the first provided to the function will be returned.
If an empty array is passed, then `FALSE` will be returned and an `E_WARNING` error will be emitted.

The values of different types will be compared using the standard comparison rules. For instance, a non-numeric string will be compared to an integer as though it were 0, but multiple non-numeric string values will be compared alphanumerically. The actual value returned will be of the original type with no conversion applied. If the first and only parameter is an array, `max()` returns the highest value in that array. If at least two parameters are provided, `max()` returns the biggest of these values.